# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, render other model on defferent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

I'm using mongoid and did't add any code after generated plain scaffold..
I'd like to render list of category on portfolio index view page.. 
so i rendered as partial. but got error as below..

```
NoMethodError in Portfs#index

Showing /Users/suri/Dev/action2/app/views/cats/_list.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% @cats.each do |cat| %>
2:  <li><%= cat.name %></li>
3: <% end %>
```

view/portf/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
        <% @portfs.each do |portf| %>
            <li class="span3"style="border:1px solid black;">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <% portf.images.each do |image| %>
                    <%= image_tag image.file.url(:small) %>
                <% end %>
                <div class="caption">
                <h3><%= link_to (truncate portf.title, :length =>10), portf %></h3>
                <p><%= truncate portf.decs, :length => 30 %></p>
                <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_portf_path(portf) %>
                <%= link_to 'Destroy', portf, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <div class="modal fade" id="portf_modal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3>Welcom to <%= image_tag 'logo.png', :height => 12 %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= form_for :portf, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :title %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :title %>
                </div>

                <%= f.label :Category %><br />
                <%= collection_select(:portf, :category, Cat.all, :name, :name) %>

                <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :decs %><br />
                <%= f.text_area :decs, :class => 'span5', :rows => 10 %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.submit '올리기', :class => 'btn btn-primary'  %>
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">닫기</a>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form class="form-search">
            <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <p>category</p>
        <% render 'cats/list', :action => "index", :controller => "cats" %>


        <a href="#portf_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">포트폴리오 올리기</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

view/cats/_list.html.erb

```
<% @cats.each do |cat| %>
    <li><%= cat.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Show us your controller. What's @cats? And why do you pass `action`, and `controller` parameters to the `render` method? I don't think they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the difference between [render partials in a view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), and [rendering in the controller context](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). It is unfortunate that both methods have the same name, but completely different use cases. When you [render in the view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), as you are doing at the bottom of your index.html.erb template, you will typically be rendering a partial. A partial is sort of like an HTML snippet that can be used to display collections of items. In your case you will need to store the collection in a `@cats` instance variable in your controller and then render a partial in your view:

In your controller:

```
@cats = Cat.all # (or any other collection of cats)
```

In your view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'cats/list' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

@cats is a instance variable that will come from your controller to your View as per the MVC architecture.  Something like

```
def index
 @cats = Cat.all
end
```

Your view/portf/index.html.erb (keeping just the last clock where you are calling your partial)

**WRONG**

```
<p>category</p>
        <% render 'cats/list', :action => "index", :controller => "cats" %>
```

**RIGHT**

```
<p>category</p>
        <%= render :partial => "list", :collection => @cats %>
```

**Correct Your Partial**

view/cats/_list.html.erb (We are not iterating the @cats loop as we have passsed the locals as collection

```
<li><%= cat.name %></li>
```